# LVM problem on upgrade to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, lvm, partitioning

I upgraded a server from 15.10 to 16.04. All went smoothly and the machine appeared in good state. However, there seems to be a problem with LVM. I have one volume group with several volumes. lvs showed all the volumes but only 2 of the 7 volumes were active. I activated the other volumes using lvchange -ay and then I can see all logical volumes in /dev/mapper. [Perhaps related to [Startup problem in 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761653/startup-problem-in-16-04-lts])

However, there appear to a problem with some of the LVs which are used as the images for virtual machines (qemu-kvm). The VMs don't boot. Moreover, previously I could mount the sub-partitions of the LV by doing a kpartx -a on the logical volume. That no longer works (e.g. kpartx -l /dev/mapper/cloud-VNAME shows nothing, while it used to show the 3 partitions of the underlying virtual machine).

One of the LVs didn't have a problem -- this just contained a data disk.

This particular problem is not too serious a problem for me because it's VM I can clone from elsewhere, but I am about to start an upgrade of all our other machines and it will be very time-consuming if I have to do this with each machine.

Does anyone have any ideas about what went wrong? How the situation could be remedied

Thanks

Scott