# I upgraded my ubuntu system and I can not start the system

Tags: fsck

I only can see the following error

```
/dev/sda1: clean, 220240/30269440 file, 2971359/121076736 blocks
```

Can someone tell me what is happening here?

Comment: That isn't an error. Are you sure it isn't starting? How long have you waited?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Ubuntu is running fsck on every bootup](http://askubuntu.com/questions/383114/my-ubuntu-is-running-fsck-on-every-bootup)

Comment: Also similar to http://askubuntu.com/questions/761653/startup-problem-in-16-04-lts

Comment: I've already waited during 15 minutes or more but is not starting