# Xubuntu 16.04 LTS - lightdm stops

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, lightdm, xserver

I am a Newbie, so pls apologize, when I do not enter all required information the first time. Pls comment, what is missing and I will bring the information ...
Thank you!

I wanted to have a remote control to a xubuntu 16.04 server. The Clients should run on Windows. 
So, on the server a clean Xubuntu was installed and also VNCServer. I accidentally installed also gdm3, but I already could remove it, It was also not working. The connection from a Windows PC worked perfect for around 5-6 times. Then the Xubuntu server did strange things after reboot.

In general,as far as I can over see it
I have a lightdm problem on a `Xubuntu 16.04 LTS with GNU/linux 4.4.0-47-generic x86_64`. It does not show any logon screen. 
Lightdm trys to start session and session and session (sometimes 14, sometimes 17), but every lightdm starting is stopped before the next lightdm session is started.

For me it seems like the Xserver does not want to communicate. This is what I've done in recovery Mode:
I have a SSD in the server,
In /etc/init/lightdm.conf before
`EXEC lightdm`
I entered

```
Sleep 10
```

In the lightdm log there is the following line, which brought me on the trace of Xserver:

```
Caught terminated signal, shutting down
```

So, I changed a bit in the system to start in terminal mode, 
In the default grub file I changed

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="TEXT"
```

In the terminal I did
`systemctl enable multi-user.target --force` and `systemctl set-default multi-user.target`

Terminal mode works fine, but I can not start the Xubuntu-desktop.

When I enter sudo apt-get -f install it says, everything fine.

How can I check, if the Xserver is running fine?

Any other ideas?
Is there a dependency between the Client opening sessions and the sessions Xubuntu wants to start during start up? If yes, can I just stop or clean?

Many thx in advance!

### Regards highway

Edit:
Hello all,
I just want to mention, what I found out: The xserver-xorg pkg was not properly installed. I fixed that, but it is still not working.
I just realized thatsince I did an upgrade, I have two Kernels installed and found a Bug on them. I corrected that, link follows to the bug report.
My next guess is, that due to the bug all installed users lost their desktop-authority ... I do not know how this is called exactly.
What I want to do next is to compare the user-account on a fresh xubuntu installation, with the one not running. 
I will update next time on Monday.

Regards Highway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed the following things to work properly:
When booting right into terminal, startx starts the Desktop.
When desktop is started, VNC-client sees a terminal.

When booting into Desktop mode, I get the known error of fchdsk
[Startup problem in 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761653/startup-problem-in-16-04-lts)
--> I have to check this at next, I just wanted to update my Question.

What I've done so far:
Reinstalling xubuntu-desktop
Reinstalling xserver-xorg and xserver-xorg-video-intel
Adding a new user account, the old is some how broken after the Update(s).

For the other problems, I open up a new Question ...

Regards!

EDIT:
Pls close the question! THX!!

Answer (score 0):

I found out, what went wrong.

During an apt-get update on the Xubuntu 16.04 with the Kernel 4.4.0-21, it has been updated to a higher version (4.4.0-47). With this update somehow, the user "user" had lost the ability to start the xubuntu-desktop.

--> By the way: Writing in /etc/init/lightdm.conf (as written in my question) had no effect. Reason: This works only on an older version of Xubuntu, ... https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/LightDM/ ...
Strange is, the old conf-file still was available ...

What I've done: I added a new user. When I enter this name in a new lightdm-conf file (named by me as 90-autologin.conf) at the autologin (just for check reasons), everything works fine now.
Directory: /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/90-autologin.conf

--> --> Additional question:

With the new user account all the old links from the broken user account are gone, so on the new account only the xubuntu-desktop runs now.

How can I repair the old user account "user"? All programs are linked to this account ... Is there a way to copy/paste those links ?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Regards Highway.

Comment: Sry, I was too fast:

Comment: Sry, I was too fast, problem is not solved, I only can start the desktop from the new user account with startx. When I set in root `systemctl enable multi-user.target --force` and 'systemctl set-default multi-user.target` and then reboot, the system starts in terminal mode.
When I do `systemctl enable graphical.target --force`and `systemctl set-default graphical.target`, I would expect the system run in desktop mode, but I get the same lightdm errors as written in the question ...

What is the difference between using graphical.target and writing startx in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Another Update:
Just to help understand this post: I am able to run a desktop from the terminal only with `startx`, but when booting directly into desktop mode, I get many errors.

What I am able to do is: Logging in via terminal-mode on a "not correct" working account. Typing `startx` I get a Xorg.0.log  (see following log-file, I needed to erase some lines! But I can assure, they are the same!).

```
[  2198.000] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.0
Release Date: 2016-11-15
[  2198.000] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  2198.000] Build Operating System: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[  2198.000] Current Operating System: Linux user-Precision-WorkStation-T5500 4.4.0-51-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 24 18:29:54 UTC 2016 x86_64
[  2198.000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic root=UUID=d3f0b684-2ce5-4820-9f23-9333fd5a852c ro net.ifnames=0 noplymouth BOOT_DEBUG=3
[  2198.000] Build Date: 23 November 2016  07:20:23PM
[  2198.000] xorg-server 2:1.19.0-2 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[  2198.000] Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
[  2198.000]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  2198.000] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  2198.001] (==) Log file: "/home/user/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Dec  5 15:25:41 2016
[  2198.001] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  2198.001] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  2198.001] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[  2198.001] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[  2198.001] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[  2198.001] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[  2198.001] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  2198.001] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  2198.001] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  2198.001] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[  2198.001] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  2198.001]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2198.001] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[  2198.001]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2198.001] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[  2198.001]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2198.001] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[  2198.001]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2198.001] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[  2198.001]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2198.001] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[  2198.001] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  2198.001] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[  2198.001] (II) Loader magic: 0x55a6312d5e00
[  2198.001] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  2198.001]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  2198.001]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[  2198.001]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[  2198.001]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[  2198.002] (++) using VT number 1

[  2198.004] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_312
[  2198.004] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[  2198.005] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 11 paused 0
[  2198.007] (--) PCI:*(0:3:0:0) 10de:05ff:10de:0661 rev 161, Mem @ 0xf6000000/16777216, 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf4000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000dc80/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[  2198.007] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  2198.007] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  2198.008] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2198.008]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 1.0.0
[  2198.008]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[  2198.008] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 0
[  2198.008] (==) Matched nv as autoconfigured driver 1
[  2198.008] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 2
[  2198.008] (==) Matched nv as autoconfigured driver 3
[  2198.008] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 4
[  2198.008] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 5
[  2198.008] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 6
[  2198.008] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[  2198.008] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[  2198.008] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[  2198.008] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2198.008]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 1.0.13
[  2198.008]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2198.008]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2198.008] (II) LoadModule: "nv"
[  2198.008] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nv
[  2198.008] (II) UnloadModule: "nv"
[  2198.008] (II) Unloading nv
[  2198.008] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
[  2198.008] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[  2198.008] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[  2198.008] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2198.008]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 1.19.0
[  2198.008]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2198.008]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2198.008] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  2198.008] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[  2198.008] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2198.008]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 0.4.4
[  2198.008]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2198.008]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2198.008] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[  2198.008] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[  2198.008] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2198.008]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 2.3.4
[  2198.008]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2198.008]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2198.008] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Tue Sep 20 00:31:06 2016 -0400
[  2198.008] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[  2198.008]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[  2198.008]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[  2198.008]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[  2198.008]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[  2198.008]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[  2198.008]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[  2198.008]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[  2198.008]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[  2198.009]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[  2198.009]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[  2198.009]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[  2198.009]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[  2198.009]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[  2198.009] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[  2198.009] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[  2198.009] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[  2198.009] xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
[  2198.009] (II) [drm] nouveau interface version: 1.3.1
[  2198.009] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
...

[  2199.537] (**) Logitech K400 Plus: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[  2199.538] (**) Logitech K400 Plus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  2199.538] (**) Logitech K400 Plus: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[  2199.538] (**) Logitech K400 Plus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  2199.538] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech K400 Plus'
[  2199.538] (II) systemd-logind: returning pre-existing fd for /dev/input/event3 13:67
[  2199.538] (**) Logitech K400 Plus: always reports core events
[  2199.538] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[  2199.538] (**) Option "_source" "_driver/libinput"
[  2199.538] (II) libinput: Logitech K400 Plus: is a virtual subdevice
[  2199.538] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb8/8-2/8-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:404D.0005/input/input6/event3"
[  2199.538] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech K400 Plus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[  2199.538] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  2199.538] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "de"
[  2199.614] (**) Option "fd" "21"
[  2199.614] (**) Option "fd" "24"
[  2199.614] (**) Option "fd" "25"
[  2199.614] (**) Option "fd" "26"
[  2199.614] (**) Option "fd" "27"
[  2199.614] (**) Option "fd" "26"
[  2199.615] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  2199.615] (II) systemd-logind: not releasing fd for 13:67, still in use
[  2199.615] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  2199.615] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:68
[  2199.628] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  2199.628] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:67
[  2199.644] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  2199.644] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:66
[  2199.668] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  2199.668] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:64
[  2199.676] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[  2199.676] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:65
[  2199.696] (II) NOUVEAU(0): NVLeaveVT is called.
[  2199.812] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

I do the same with a correct working account, (see "good.log").
When Comparing both logs, some Options on the end of the bad.log are too much.

```
[  1006.471] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.0
Release Date: 2016-11-15
[  1006.473] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  1006.473] Build Operating System: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[  1006.474] Current Operating System: Linux user-Precision-WorkStation-T5500 4.4.0-51-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 24 18:29:54 UTC 2016 x86_64
[  1006.474] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic root=UUID=d3f0b684-2ce5-4820-9f23-9333fd5a852c ro net.ifnames=0 plymouth BOOT_DEBUG=3
[  1006.475] Build Date: 23 November 2016  07:20:23PM
[  1006.476] xorg-server 2:1.19.0-2 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[  1006.476] Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
[  1006.477]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  1006.477] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  1006.479] (==) Log file: "/home/otto/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Dec  5 16:20:11 2016
[  1006.480] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1006.480] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  1006.480] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[  1006.480] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[  1006.480] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[  1006.480] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[  1006.480] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  1006.480] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  1006.480] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  1006.480] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[  1006.480] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  1006.480]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1006.480] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[  1006.480]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1006.480] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[  1006.480]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1006.480] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[  1006.480]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1006.480] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[  1006.480]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1006.480] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[  1006.480] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  1006.480] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[  1006.480] (II) Loader magic: 0x55f5645fce00
[  1006.480] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  1006.480]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  1006.480]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[  1006.480]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[  1006.480]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[  1006.481] (++) using VT number 1

[  1006.483] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_33
[  1006.484] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[  1006.484] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 11 paused 0
[  1006.486] (--) PCI:*(0:3:0:0) 10de:05ff:10de:0661 rev 161, Mem @ 0xf6000000/16777216, 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf4000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000dc80/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[  1006.486] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  1006.486] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  1006.487] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1006.487]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 1.0.0
[  1006.487]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[  1006.487] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 0
[  1006.487] (==) Matched nv as autoconfigured driver 1
[  1006.487] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 2
[  1006.487] (==) Matched nv as autoconfigured driver 3
[  1006.487] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 4
[  1006.487] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 5
[  1006.487] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 6
[  1006.487] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[  1006.487] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[  1006.487] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[  1006.487] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1006.487]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 1.0.13
[  1006.487]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1006.487]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  1006.487] (II) LoadModule: "nv"
[  1006.487] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nv
[  1006.487] (II) UnloadModule: "nv"
[  1006.487] (II) Unloading nv
[  1006.487] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
[  1006.487] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[  1006.487] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[  1006.487] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1006.487]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 1.19.0
[  1006.487]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1006.487]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  1006.487] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  1006.487] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[  1006.487] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1006.487]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 0.4.4
[  1006.487]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1006.487]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  1006.487] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[  1006.487] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[  1006.488] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1006.488]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 2.3.4
[  1006.488]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1006.488]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  1006.488] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Tue Sep 20 00:31:06 2016 -0400
[  1006.488] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[  1006.488]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[  1006.488]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[  1006.488]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[  1006.488]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[  1006.488]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[  1006.488]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[  1006.488]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[  1006.488]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[  1006.488]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[  1006.488]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[  1006.488]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[  1006.488]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[  1006.488]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[  1006.488] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[  1006.488] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[  1006.488] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[  1006.488] xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
[  1006.488] (II) [drm] nouveau interface version: 1.3.1
[  1006.488] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting keyboard

......

[  1008.009] (**) Logitech K400 Plus: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[  1008.009] (**) Logitech K400 Plus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  1008.009] (**) Logitech K400 Plus: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[  1008.009] (**) Logitech K400 Plus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  1008.009] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech K400 Plus'
[  1008.009] (II) systemd-logind: returning pre-existing fd for /dev/input/event3 13:67
[  1008.009] (**) Logitech K400 Plus: always reports core events
[  1008.009] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[  1008.010] (**) Option "_source" "_driver/libinput"
[  1008.010] (II) libinput: Logitech K400 Plus: is a virtual subdevice
[  1008.010] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb8/8-2/8-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:404D.0004/input/input6/event3"
[  1008.010] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech K400 Plus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[  1008.010] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  1008.010] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "de"
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): EDID vendor "LEN", prod id 2572
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Using EDID range info for horizontal sync
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Using EDID range info for vertical refresh
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  146.30  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz eP)
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x72.0  132.75  1280 1368 1504 1728  1024 1025 1028 1067 -hsync +vsync (76.8 kHz e)
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0   88.75  1440 1488 1520 1600  900 903 909 926 +hsync -vsync (55.5 kHz e)
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  136.75  1440 1536 1688 1936  900 903 909 942 -hsync +vsync (70.6 kHz e)
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1600x900"x60.0  119.00  1600 1696 1864 2128  900 901 904 932 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
[  1008.266] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): EDID vendor "LEN", prod id 2572
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  146.30  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz eP)
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x72.0  132.75  1280 1368 1504 1728  1024 1025 1028 1067 -hsync +vsync (76.8 kHz e)
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0   88.75  1440 1488 1520 1600  900 903 909 926 +hsync -vsync (55.5 kHz e)
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  136.75  1440 1536 1688 1936  900 903 909 942 -hsync +vsync (70.6 kHz e)
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1600x900"x60.0  119.00  1600 1696 1864 2128  900 901 904 932 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
[  1008.955] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
```

Can anyone tell me, where I can find the startx-options in the home-directory `[**] Option "fd" "21"` etc.? I want to erase them :)

Thank you!

P.S.: If more Info is needed from the log, pls let me know! THX!