# Playing a movie causes to logout with showing error: /dev/sda1: clean, xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, 17.04

Just upgraded to xubuntu 17.04. Whenever I play a movie file (`*.ogv` either with vlc or parole) after few seconds a black screen shows up with `/dev/sda1: clean, xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks`, the screen stays for few seconds and returns back to the login screen! There seems to be [similar issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761653/startup-problem-in-16-04) asked before on startup. However I do not have any issue on startup, this just happens after playing movie files.

I downgraded to xubuntu 16.04.2, and the same issue persists. I did not have this problem on xubuntu 16.04 before.

Any idea what causes the problem?

Edit:

```
sudo ls -al /var/crash

total 13016
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie     4096 Apr 29 13:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root         4096 Feb 15 12:27 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root whoopsie        0 Apr 29 13:04 .lock
-rw-r-----  1 root whoopsie 13317966 Apr 29 13:18 _usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash
```

and

```
sudo head -20 /var/crash/_usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash

ProblemType: Crash
Architecture: amd64
CrashCounter: 1
Date: Sat Apr 29 13:18:17 2017
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 16.04
ExecutablePath: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
ExecutableTimestamp: 1485390561
ProcCmdline: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
ProcCwd: /
ProcEnviron: 
ProcMaps:
 55ddea9e7000-55ddeac23000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 797435                     /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
 55ddeae23000-55ddeae25000 r--p 0023c000 08:11 797435                     /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
 55ddeae25000-55ddeae32000 rw-p 0023e000 08:11 797435                     /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
 55ddeae32000-55ddeae43000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 55ddec210000-55ddedd29000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
 7f506594e000-7f5065cce000 rw-s 10cab4000 00:06 360                       /dev/dri/card0
 7f5065cce000-7f5065d1e000 rw-s 10ca53000 00:06 360                       /dev/dri/card0
 7f5065d1e000-7f506609e000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 129134                     /drm mm object (deleted)
 7f506609e000-7f506619e000 rw-s 10c903000 00:06 360                       /dev/dri/card0
```

The graphic card:

```
sudo lshw -C video

  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:27 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

and the driver:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `ls -al /var/crash`, and I'll take a look.

Comment: I've edited the question @heynnema.

Comment: What video card and driver are you using?

Comment: ps: how much RAM? How much swap?

Comment: I have 24GB RAM and 16GB swap. I monitored them during crash and they are usually around 10% RAM and 0% swap. I should also add that I can open video files in firefox without crashing.

Comment: Wow. I'm already out of ideas on how I can help. Maybe there's enough info in your question for somebody else to get an idea.